# Can XACT_ABORT be overriden by sql server settings so that setting this to on has no effect?

Tags: sql-server

Can XACT_ABORT be overriden by sql server settings so that setting this to "ON"
has no effect?

Thanks!

P.S. I ask about sql server 2005 db.

Answer (score 0):

Setting it to ON will be effective for a session